# schema.org for items that are not for sale?

Tags: microdata

Is there any schema for items that are not for sale? (example: stamps from a catalog).
I saw "Product" but I'm not sure if it ok to describe with it a stamp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t sell it, but do you offer it in some other way (e.g., gratis or for trade)? If not, [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) is not appropriate, because it is only for an "*offered* product or service" (emphasis mine).

You can start from [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) (which can be used if there is no more specific type available). It currently has the following child types:

- `Action`
- `BroadcastService`
- `CreativeWork`
- `Event`
- `Intangible`
- `MedicalEntity`
- `Organization`
- `Person`
- `Place`
- `Product`

For stamps, I think we can exclude everything except [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) (and [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) in case you’d offer it). Looking at child types from `CreativeWork`, there doesn’t seem to be a closer match for generic stamps (while [`DataCatalog`](http://schema.org/DataCatalog)+[`Dataset`](http://schema.org/Dataset) could work, I guess it’s not intended for such kinds of collections).

So without further background information, I’d go with [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork).